# Dividing by zero

Tags: limits

I'm studying this function and I have this limit.

I think the domain is $x\neq0$ so it can't be calculated the limit for $x \rightarrow 0^-$.

$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \dfrac{ 1-2lnx }{ x^2 }$

Now I'm stuck because $1-2lnx$ tends to $-1$ and $x^2$ tends to $0^+$ so I tought the result would be $-\infty$ but Wolfram says it's generic infinite $\infty$ and in the graph it shows $+\infty$.

Comment: $1-2\ln x \to +\infty$ as $x \to 0+$.

Comment: $\ln x$ approaches $-\infty$ here, not $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact the domain of $f(x) = \frac{1-2 \ln x}{x^2}$is not $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ but $\mathbb R_+$ as $\ln x$ is only defined for $x \gt 0$.

Now as both $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} 1-2 \ln x = \lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1}{x^2} = \infty$, you get $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = \infty$.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand if it's also correct to say the result is $+\infty$ instead of generic infinite or we can't assume that?

Comment: @Giustinian0: $\infty$ and $+\infty$ are synonyms in this context.